# In SQL Server, how do you update table from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here are my two tables:

```
Table1
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+
| Address1  | Address2  | Unit1 | Unit2 | Precinct |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+
| 150       | Oak St    | 0     | 10    | 1111     |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+

Table2
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+
| Address1  | Address2  | Unit1 | Unit2 | Precinct |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+
| 150       | Oak St    | 0     | 10    | 1111     |
| 150       | Oak St    | 0     | 10    | 2222     |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+----------+
```

What I'm trying to do is copy date from Table2 (source) over to Table1 (target) like this:

- Match on Address1, Address2, Unit1, Unit2
- if precinct is the same, don't do anything
- if precinct is different, append with a comma ("1111" to "1111, 2222")

This is what I tried:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.Precinct = 
    CASE
        WHEN t1.Precinct LIKE '%' + t2.Precinct + '%' THEN t1.Precinct
        ELSE t1.Precinct + ',' + t2.Precinct
    END
FROM Table1 t1 join Table2 t2 on t1.Address1 = t2.Address1 and t1.Address2 = t2.Address2 and t1.Unit1 = t2.Unit1 and t1.Unit2 = t2.Unit2
```

My expected result is this:

```
Expected Result (Table1)
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+
| Address1  | Address2  | Unit1 | Unit2 | Precinct  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 150       | Oak St    | 0     | 10    | 1111,2222 |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

but what I get is this:

```
Actual Result (Table1) (Nothing changes)
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+
| Address1  | Address2  | Unit1 | Unit2 | Precinct  |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+
| 150       | Oak St    | 0     | 10    | 1111      |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

I played around with it a little bit and found out that since the match on (address1, address2, unit1, unit2) has 2 results in the Source table, the query only ends up looking at the first row (precinct=1111) and never looking at the second row.

How can I work around this? Is my current approach the complete wrong approach?

Comment: You need to group Table2 by the fields other than `Precinct`. You could use `string_agg` to get the `Precinct` value.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without string_agg? Unfortunately there is some extra logic I wanted to add to the WHEN clause that I left out for simplicity's purposes. In my app the Precint column is JSON, so I would be adding to that.

Comment: It is an art, but please don't dumb down your problem. If the question you ask is simpler than the problem you have, people waste time on the wrong answers.

Comment: Ah, will keep that in mind! Don't have much experience on stackoverflow (posting, at least), so still learning.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't going to work.  First, storing values in comma-delimited lists is strongly discouraged.  But if you *must* do this, you need to aggregate `table2` first.  An `update` updates a row only once.

So:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.Precinct = t1.Precinct + ',' + t2.Precincts
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT address1, address2, unit1, unit2,
             STRING_AGG(Precinct, ',') as precincts
      FROM Table2 t2
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM table1 t1
                        WHERE t1.Address1 = t2.Address1 AND
                              t1.Address2 = t2.Address2 AND
                              t1.Unit1 = t2.Unit1 AND
                              t1.Unit2 = t2.Unit2 AND
                              ',' + t1.precinct + ',' LIKE '%,' + t2.precinct + ',%'
                      )
      GROUP BY address1, address2, unit1, unit2
     ) t2
     ON t1.Address1 = t2.Address1 AND
        t1.Address2 = t2.Address2 AND
        t1.Unit1 = t2.Unit1 AND
        t1.Unit2 = t2.Unit2
```